# Pagination on url cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination

I created an API using cakephp and I created a custom json output for get method . You can see below the output for a GET for a specific id

https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9oQ4.jpg

my url now is : **localhost:8765/api/drones/6153/**

my problem is how to custom the url so I can add the pagination and to change the url like **localhost:8765/api/drones/6153/page:1**

this my route's code :

```
 Router::connect('/api/drones/:id', ['controller' => 'Drones', 'action' => 'view', 'prefix' => 'api'],['id' => '\d+', 'pass' => ['id']]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add one more parameter within the pass-> page

```
 Router::connect('/api/drones/:id', 
   ['controller' => 'Drones', 'action' => 'view', 'prefix' => 'api'],
   [
     'id'   => '\d+', 
     'pass' => ['id', 'page']       // Add page along with id
   ]
);
```

Comment: Hey, It didn't work . I got an Error message : **Action DronesController::6153() could not be found, or is not accessible.**. code 404 , Cake\\Controller\\Exception\\MissingActionException